# PuTTY configuration with plink for keyboard-interactive authentication

Tags: ssh, authentication, putty, bastion

**Please see EDIT #2 for latest findings**

I've looked at other similar questions but, unfortunately, none of them seemed to help. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300259/please-debug-ssh-proxy-command-it-cannot-connect-remote-server-with-multihop-ss) is the closest and my symptoms are similar.

Here's the issue:

1. I am trying to setup the equivalent of `ProxyJump` via PuTTY, from Windows workstation A to Linux box (MFA protected, password first) B to Linux target C
2. My proxy command is `plink.exe -agent -l <user> %proxyhost -nc %host:%port\n`
3. Upon initiating a connection to C, I just see a window that says

> Starting local proxy command: plink.exe -agent -l  B -nc C:22

and simply hangs there.

In PuTTY log I see

`Using keyboard-interactive authentication
.Password:`

but that password prompt never shows up on screen and the open window won't take any input.

Any suggestions on what I might have missed?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Cheers!

EDIT #1: Upon further experimentation, it turns out this issue has to do with any keyboard-interactive second factor. Even I changed from Azure MFA to Duo, I still see the same behavior.

The output from the remote server is never tied back to the PuTTY terminal - I wonder if plink has anything to do with this, since it's intended behavior is similar to `ProxyCommand` otherwise. Perhaps something to do with how pipes to and from remote sessions are handled?

EDIT #2: This is almost certainly now an issue with plink and keyboard-interactive authentication. I tried `PubKeyAuthentication` only as well as `GSSAPIAuthentication` only and both of them work fine. I then tried `PasswordAuthentication` only and it failed.

I've updated the post title accordingly.

Comment: Do you have putty agent running with a valid key loaded?

Comment: The first factor is a password, not key, so I don't have any keys loaded

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the multi-factor part of the question. That might be pretty tricky to handle on Windows.  Is using the [Microsoft openssh port](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) an option, or running WSL and using SSH in WSL an option?  Both those should basically offer identical functionality to the linux systems.